# Wrong values when merging raster files

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, merge, aster

I am trying to merge several (70 at least) raster files (a digital elevation model, ASTER DEM v2). I am using QGIS and I use the tool "Raster > Miscellaneous > Merge".

I works well and I get the new raster, but the elevation values are not concordant with the values on the original rasters. For instance, there are individual rasters with elevation >2000m, and in the new raster I get values until 1500m.

I have also used "Raster > Miscellaneous > Build Virtual Raster", but the same happens. I have tried as well to merge fewer raster files; it still does not work.

What should I do? Any suggestions?

Comment: been having the exact same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to properties of the ASTER DEM layer and go to Style and do the following:

[image]

1. Use Min/Max
2. In the Extent, use Actual (Slower) => Load. Then check if the pixel values were updated or not.

Comment: After that, the range values are still the same... In the layer with the merged raster files and in the individual rasters...

Comment: Have you tried both "Full extent" and "Current extent"?

Comment: I am trying now. This takes a while, maybe the last time I tried I didn't give it enough time. I will let you know if this works!

Comment: The values change with the options "full extent" and "Actual (slower)". But it seems to take a very long time, I wasn't able to let the "load" finish yet... Do you know of any other option? Maybe using GRASS...?